# Replacing strings in a 2d python list

Tags: python, string, list, loops

I am reading in a text file as lines and then splitting those lines by white space, giving me a 2d list. Some of the strings in the embedded arrays contain junk that I'm trying to filter out using `str.replace`, but it's not working.

```
import os

infile = 'CMULEX.txt'

data = []
with open(infile, 'r') as f:
    read_data = f.readlines()

    for row in read_data[:5]:
        split_line = (row.split())
        data.append(split_line)

for line in data[:5]:
    for wd in line:
        wd = wd.replace('Coda', '')
```

Comment: "I know that the" ... I think you omitted the end.

Comment: can you show us part of the CMULEX.txt?

Comment: You're not *assigning* the result back into the list item, just the `wd` loop variable.

Comment: `wd.replace("Coda, "")` is a syntax error. It should be `wd.replace("Coda", "")`.

Comment: How do I assign it back to the list item?

Answer (score 1):

`wd` is a local variable. It's not a "pointer" back to the list. A list comprehension seems like an elegant solution here:

```
for row in read_data[:5]:
    split_line = (row.split())
    data.append([wd.replace("Coda", "") for wd in split_line])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
For line in data[:5]:
   line[:] = [ '' if x == 'Coda' else x for x in line]
```

Comment: The code is wrong. It replaces `line` in place instead of replacing it in `data`.

Comment: He never mentioned that he wants to replace the data. He simply wants a filtered output. He can perform desired manipulation on line itself.